# Regular expression for numbers in R

Tags: regex, r, decimal, points

I need to write a regular expression to parse the following data:

```
[1] "Chicken (30.67%);Duck (17.3%);Wild duck (16%);Pigeon (4%);
[2] "Chicken (30.67%);Duck (17.3%);Wild duck (16%);Blue-winged teal (4%)
```

This is what I have:

```
"(\\w[\\w\\s]+)\\(([0-9]+\\.[0-9][0-9]?)%\\);?"
```

It works but I have a couple of problems:

- It doesn't recognize the 10+% (e.g. 30.67%)
- It doesn't recognize when absent of decimal point (16%) or 1 decimal point less (17.3%)

Can anyone help?

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: Try `(\\w+(?:\\s+\\w+)*)\\s*\\(([0-9]+(\\.[0-9]+)?)%\)`. Have a look at [the demo](https://regex101.com/r/zC3gS4/1).

Answer (score 1):

This should help:

```
   library(stringr)
    str_extract_all(text, pattern = "[0-9]{1,2}(\\.[0-9]{1,2})?%")
```

---

Explanation of the regex:

```
[0-9]{1,2} there are one or two digits between 0-9
  (        start Group
    \\.    a dot (have to escape it with double backslash, otherwise special character
    [0-9]{1,2} there are one or two digits between 0-9
  )?       end group, group may exists, but must not
 %         percent dign
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: Does this explanation help?

Comment: You're welcome! Maybe you can accept the answer as correct than to close this issue? Thnaks

Comment: Not my question, this answer was in the LQ post review queue, so I used my "canned text" on any code-only answers.  Have an upvote, but it's on the asker to accept.

Answer (score 1):

Just use my suggested regex:

```
(\\w+(?:\\s+\\w+)*)\\s*\\(([0-9]+(?:\\.[0-9]+)?)%\\);?
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/zC3gS4/2)

And the R code sample:

```
library(stringr)
str_extract_all(str, "(\\w+(?:\\s+\\w+)*)\\s*\\(([0-9]+(?:\\.[0-9]+)?)%\\);?")[[1]]
```

Comment: Please let me know if it works for you, oe you need more clarifications.